# The right test to check whether the two tables are independent from each other

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, descriptive-statistics

**Table A**

| Group | Year 1 | Year 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.4 | 0.45 |
| 2 | 0.3 | 0.33 |
| 3 | 0.2 | 0.6 |
| 4 | 0.1 | 0.12 |
| 5 | 0.07 | 0.11 |
| 6 | 0.03 | 0.06 |
| 7 | 0.01 | 0.02 |

**Table B**

| Group | Year 1 | Year 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.43 | 0.42 |
| 2 | 0.313 | 0.39 |
| 3 | 0.223 | 0.65 |
| 4 | 0.112 | 0.18 |
| 5 | 0.065 | 0.105 |
| 6 | 0.031 | 0.054 |
| 7 | 0.012 | 0.018 |

I have two tables named as A and B. the numbers in the tables are probabilities of each group in each year. I would like to check whether the probabilities are statistically different for Year 1 in **Table A** from Year 1 in **Table B**. For example, I would like to say the probabilities for Year 1 are significantly different in Table B from Table A.

I am not sure which test should I go with and how to formulate it.

Comment: It depends on where those probabilities came from.  You never directly measure a probability: it's a construct in a model and can only be estimated.  But *how* you estimate the probabilities and *the nature of the data* used for those estimates play an important role in a test.  Please clarify your situation.